# React not rendering child on different Layout separated with switch and route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have this react project that have 2 Layouts , Main and Admin .
I have handled routing on a third component with switch and route .
Main Layout is working properly but Admin does not Render any child .

This is where I handle Routing :

```
return (
<LoadingOverlay active={loading} text={<Loading text={loadingText} />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={["/AdminPanel"]}>
          <AdminLayout>
            <Route
              path="/AdminPanel"
              exact
              render={() =>
                !isEmpty(user) && user.role === "Admin" ? (
                  <AdminDashBoard />
                ) : (
                  <Redirect to="404" />
                )
              }
            />
          </AdminLayout>
        </Route>

        <Route path={["/"]}>
          <MainLayout>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/Archive" component={Archive} />
              <Route path="/Course/:id" component={SingleCourse} />
              <Route path="/DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
              <Route
                path="/Login"
                render={() => (
                  <UserGlobalState setLoading={setLoading}>
                    <Login />
                  </UserGlobalState>
                )}
              />
              <Route
                path="/Logout"
                render={() =>
                  isEmpty(user) ? (
                    <Redirect to="/" />
                  ) : (
                    <Logout setLoading={setLoading} />
                  )
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/Register"
                render={() =>
                  isEmpty(user) ? (
                    <UserGlobalState setLoading={setLoading}>
                      <Register />
                    </UserGlobalState>
                  ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/" />
                  )
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                render={() => <HomePageCourses courses={indexCourses} />}
              />
              <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </MainLayout>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </LoadingOverlay>
    )
```

Here is `AdminLayout.jsx` :

```
const AdminLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllUsers());
  }, []);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Helmet>
        <title>AdminPanel</title>
      </Helmet>

      <Navbar />

      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <SideBar />

            <div className="col-md-9">
              <div className="content">
                
                {children}

                <div className="module">
                  <div className="module-head">
                    <h3>Adjust Budget Range</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div className="module-body">
                    <div className="form-inline clearfix">
                      <a href="#" className="btn pull-right">
                        Update
                      </a>
                      <label htmlFor="amount">Price range:</label>
                      &nbsp;
                      <input type="text" id="amount" className="input-" />
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div className="slider-range"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="footer">
        <div className="container">
          <b className="copyright">&copy; 2021 Saeed RayatMoghadam </b>All
          rights reserved.
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Here is `AdminDashBoard.jsx` :

```
return (
        <div className="btn-controls">
          <div className="btn-box-row row-fluid">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="btn-box big cursor-pointer">
                <i
                  className="glyphicon glyphicon-book"
                  style={{ fontSize: "35px" }}
                ></i>
                <b>{courses.length}</b>
                <p className="text-muted">Course`s</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 cursor-pointer">
              <div className="btn-box big">
                <i className="zmdi zmdi-accounts"></i>
                <b>{users.length}</b>
                <p className="text-muted">Users</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 cursor-pointer">
              <div className="btn-box big">
                <i className="zmdi zmdi-money-box"></i>
                <b>15,152</b>
                <p className="text-muted">Profit</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="btn-box-row row-fluid">
            <div className="col-md-8" style={{ padding: "0" }}>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <div className="btn-box small">
                  <i className="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>
                  <b>Messages</b>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <div className="btn-box small">
                  <i className="icon-group"></i>
                  <b>Clients</b>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <div className="btn-box small">
                  <i className="icon-exchange"></i>
                  <b>Expenses</b>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <ul className="widget widget-usage unstyled w-100">
                <li>
                  <h2 style={{ color: "black" }}>
                    Users{" "}
                    <span className="badge badge-primary">{users.length}</span>
                  </h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    <strong>
                      <i className="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
                      {"  "} Admin`s
                    </strong>{" "}
                    <span className="pull-right small badge badge-danger">{adminsPercentage}%</span>
                  </p>
                  <div className="progress tight">
                    <div className="bar" style={{ width: `${adminsPercentage}%` }}></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    <strong>
                      <i className="zmdi zmdi-account-box-mail"></i>
                      {"  "} Teacher`s
                    </strong>{" "}
                    <span className="pull-right small badge badge-danger">{teachersPercentage}%</span>
                  </p>
                  <div className="progress tight">
                    <div className="bar bar-success" style={{ width: `${teachersPercentage}%` }}></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <p>
                    <strong>
                      <i className="zmdi zmdi-graduation-cap"></i>
                      {"   "} Student`s
                    </strong>{" "}
                    <span className="pull-right small badge badge-danger">{studentsPercentage}%</span>
                  </p>
                  <div className="progress tight">
                    <div className="bar bar-warning" style={{ width: `${studentsPercentage}%` }}></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
```

Everything is working properly
It does render AdminLayout but not the children

I always handle layouts and routing like this but this is the first time having this issue.
by the way there is no error on console.

Even if I render `AdminDashBoard` in `AdminLayout` instead of its children its gonna work properly but nothing when using children.

Anyone has any Idea why it's happening ?

Comment: Is the URL path your are navigating to *exactly* `"/AdminPanel"`?

Comment: Yes Exactly , as I said if I use AdminDashBoard in the Layout its gonna work

Comment: Its not just that route no route is gonna work

Comment: The outer route on "/AdminPanel" will match any "/AdminPanel*" path and render the `AdminLayout` component, but if the inner route is ***not*** exactly "/AdminPanel" then it won't be matched and rendered as a child.

Comment: yea its exactly same . but I found out that user that is in redux is null here on condition although I have it in redux dev tool . its not only this other routes like login , logout and register that has a condition based on user is not working anymore . do you have any idea why is it null ? I can get user everywhere else but here

Comment: I see. Can you update your question to include the new relevant code? What is `user`, where is it defined, and how is it updated?

Comment: Thank you for your help I fixed it by getting the user from its token in local storage